# Retrieve fix number of frames from vector in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I read a video and stored all the frames in a vector. Now I want to stitch first 50 frames that are stored in vector and save the result, after that stitch next 50 frames and save the result and so on. This is because the stitching class of opencv don't process large number of frames at once and gives the error: insufficient memory. I am unable to implement the correct logic. Kindly help me correct the code. Thanks. My code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::string video_file;
    // Read video file
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        video_file = argv[1];
    }
    else
    {
        video_file = "vid/xyz.mp4";
    }

    VideoCapture inputVideo(video_file);
    if (!inputVideo.isOpened())
        cerr << "Error opening video file\n";

    double totalFrames(inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT));
    double frameRate(inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS));
    double timeInterval = 0.5; // in sec
    int sizeReduction = 4;
    int num = 1;


    vector<Mat> frames;
    vector<Mat> frames1;
    Mat frame;

    for (int num = 0; num < totalFrames; num++)
    {
        num = num + round(frameRate * timeInterval);
        inputVideo.set(1, num);
        inputVideo >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
            continue;
        cv::Size sz = frame.size();
        cv::resize(frame, frame, sz / sizeReduction);
        frames.push_back(frame);   // vector 'frames' have all the frames to be processed
    }

    Stitcher::Mode mode = Stitcher::SCANS;
    string result_name = "xyz.jpg";
    vector<Mat> pano1;
    Mat pano;
    Ptr<Stitcher> stitcher = Stitcher::create(mode);

    int f1, f2 = 0;
    // need help to correct the code below: 
    for (f1 = f2; f1 <= frames.size(); f1++) {
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 50) {
            frames1.push_back(frames[f1]);  // I want to save first 10 frames in vector 'frames1'
            count++;
            }
        Stitcher::Status status = stitcher->stitch(frames1, pano);
        pano1.push_back(pano);
        f2 = f2 + count;            
    }

    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher->stitch(pano1, pano); 
    imwrite(result_name, pano);
    cout << "stitching completed successfully\n" << result_name << " saved!";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Does the program works for 50 frames? why 50? Do you have error for less than 50 frames?

Answer (score 0):

You are storing all the frames in a `vector` first and only after you run the algorithm to stitch them together. That's a lot of memory wasted.

A better approach is to read the first two frames and stitch them together to create a panorama. Then read the third frame and stitch it to the existing panorama. Then read the fourth and stitch it, and then the fifth... and so on.

There's no need to keep all those frames stored in a vector.